# How can I return a 0 from a function that parses a string to find an int if it finds a number with a decimal point?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public int GetIntSetting(Settings setting, int nullState)
{
    var s = GetStringSetting(setting);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return nullState;
    return int.Parse(s);
}
```

If the value of `s` is something like 1.234 then the functions creates an exception.

How can I make it so that if the value of `s` has a decimal point then the function returns 0?

Comment: How would you differentiate between the user entered zero or just `1.234`? Throwing an exception on invalid user-input is okay.

Comment: not an expert of c# but you can probably parse it to a decimal/float type and check it is the same value than the int one.

Comment: if (s.Contains(",") || s.Contains("."))
    return 0

?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try searching before asking a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int parsed;
var result = int.TryParse(data, out parsed) ? parsed : 0;
```

Or if using C#7.0 with the out var declaration:

```
var result = int.TryParse(data, int out parsed) ? parsed : 0;
```

*Note that as HimBromBeere commented you will not know when it is 0 because it is not a valid int or because the input is actually the input*.

All together:

```
public int GetIntSetting(Settings setting, int nullState)
{
    var s = GetStringSetting(setting);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return nullState;
    return int.TryParse(s, out int parsed) ? parsed : 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `int.TryParse(data, out int result)`?

Comment: @SivaGopal - yap, my mistake. Corrected

Comment: Actually I just realized.  I only need to check the string for the existence of a "."  I think that would be maybe more clean.

Comment: @Alan - that depends - do you know 100% that the string will not have letters in it? It is just safer to use `TryParse` when parsing to int, instead of getting an exception..  (unless that's the desired response)

Comment: @Alan - especially with C#7.0 it is nice and inline to check it

Comment: Do you mean to have s instead of data ?

Comment: @Alan - yes. ops :) correcting now

Answer (score 2):

`int.TryParse` will return false for decimal numbers. This is a bit broader than your question of *jiust* handling decimal points, but is probably a sensible thing to do anyway:

```
int x = 0;
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse("1.234",out x)); // outputs False
```

So you could change your code to

```
public int GetIntSetting(Settings setting, int nullState)
{
    var s = GetStringSetting(setting);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) )
        return nullState;
    var result = 0;
    if(!int.TryParse(s,out result))
        return 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Actually I just realized.  I only need to check the string for the existence of a "."  I think that would be maybe more clean.

Comment: So a setting for `abc123$%$£!%"&` is an acceptable `int` to you?

Comment: @Alan If you have another solution to your problem feel free to post an answer yourself. However in this particular case I won´t recommend that because of the previously mentioned comment from Jamiec.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose TryParse testing if it would parse as an int or a double:

```
double theNumber;
if (Int32.TryParse(s, out theNumber)) return (int)theNumber;
else if (Double.TryParse(s, theNumber)) return 0;

// Here is not an int or double, i.e. return nullState for example
```

Comment: Actually I just realized.  I only need to check the string for the existence of a "."  I think that would be maybe more clean.